# SSL Certificate Pinning in iOS with Microsoft Azure SDK

Tags: ios, azure, ssl, pinning, certificate-pinning

#### This is not a question about certificate pinning in general.

I am writing an iOS app that utilizes the Microsoft Azure SDK for iOS. They have not implemented certificate pinning, so I have downloaded the full SDK and I am modifying it to add in my own pinning.

I am following the example code given by OWASP. It asks me to execute the following code in Terminal:

```
$ echo "Get HTTP/1.0" | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.random.org:443
```

I have run that, swapping in my `{url}.azurewebsites.net` for `www.random.org`. I get back a good output, with several certificates listed.

Based on the OWASP code, it appears that I am supposed to use this one:

```
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=*.azurewebsites.net
   i:/C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/OU=Microsoft IT/CN=Microsoft IT SSL SHA2
```

What concerns me about this is that the `CN` is for a wildcard `*.azurewebsites.net`. Does this mean that if I use this certificate and someone attempted a man-in-the-middle attack utilizing another Azure web app, that certificate pinning would succeed for them, thereby failing to protect my app?

For instance, if my app is at `abc.azurewebsites.net` and the man-in-the-middle attack is run from `xyz.azurewebsites.net`, would my app know to block the request?

Answer (score 0):

An attacker, that has registered `xyz.azurewebsites.net` in Azure, can not perform a MitM attack using `xyz.azurewebsites.net`, because he does not know the private key. Only Azure knows the value of the private key.

So, this is not because somebody that has registered `xyz.azurewebsites.net` is able to intercept communications between your app and `abc.azurewebsites.net`, that he could deceive your app. But note that this has nothing to do with public key pinning of certificates.

**First, let's talk about public key pinning of a certificate you do not own.**

In such a case, be very careful about the fact that if you had to manage your server certificate, you could reuse the same key each time you had to ask a CA to issue a new certificate for you. So, you could avoid implementing what OWASP calls **key continuity** (see https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning). BUT in your case, Microsoft is allowed to use a new key when issuing a new certificate. In this case, you app would stop working, and this is not what you want. So, you should implement key continuity when pinning.

So, if you had in mind to simply implement a statically pinned key in your app, I think it's dangerous. Microsoft can change the public key when they want. For instance, is their private key is stolen, they will generate a new certificate with a new public key (and they will revoke the previous certificate). In such a case, you application will see a new key, but should not stop the request.

**Now, let's talk about public key pinning with key continuity of a wildcard certificate.**

1- First, suppose that somebody successfully managed to issue a real certificate for `*.azurewebsites.net`. Since your app is using public key pinning of the wildcard certificate, you app will see that this certificate does not contain the right public key. So, your app will block the request.

2- Now, suppose that somebody successfully managed to issue a real certificate for `xyz.azurewebsites.net`. So your app will see that the certificate is neither `abc.azurewebsites.net` nor `*.azurewebsites.net`. So your app will stop the request.

3- Finally, suppose that somebody successfully managed to issue a real certificate for `abc.azurewebsites.net`. Your app will see a correct certificate for `abc.azurewebsites.net`. So, you need to code an error in your app, for it to stop the request, because you know Azure does not issue such certificates.

Comment: So, if I correctly check for Microsoft's public key via the method described by OWASP, I can consider my app hardened against MitM attacks?

Comment: I've updated my answer, I do not know if you have read the new version before writing your comment. Anyway, I think you should consider the third case in my answer: if your app sees a certificate for abc.azurewebsites.net, your app will not look at a pinned key because the pinned keys can only be associated with a previously seen certificate. So, if you only implement what OWASP explains, you will not be protected against somebody that could issue a real certificate for abc.azurewebsites.net. To be protected against such an attacker, you must stop the request if you see such a certificate.

Comment: I did read your answer (several times during the edits; lol). Regarding #3, if someone does get a certificate for that domain (which they shouldn't, right, since Microsoft owns it?), wouldn't the credential check still fail, since the certificate data wouldn't match the pinned certificate data?

Comment: Microsoft owns the domain, but if somebody hacks a Certificate Authority, not the one used by Microsoft but any other, he could issue a certificate for this domain. So, without hacking Microsoft, it could be possible to issue a certificate for this domain. See http://www.slate.com/articles/technology/future_tense/2016/12/how_the_2011_hack_of_diginotar_changed_the_internet_s_infrastructure.html for instance.

Comment: Ok, so now I'm checking both the server certificate against my locally-pinned one and also checking that the url for the server certificate is `*.azurewebsites.net`. Does that cover all my bases? But I'm still not seeing how someone issuing another (valid) certificate is a problem. It won't pass the certificate comparison, as long as my original (pinned) certificate is really from Microsoft, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Be very careful about the fact that if you had to manage your server certificate, you could reuse the same key each time you had to ask a CA to issue a new certificate for you. So, you could avoid implementing what OWASP calls "key continuity" (see https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning). BUT in your case, Microsoft is allowed to issue a new certificate with a new key. In this case, you app would stop working, and this is not what you want. So, you should implement key continuity.

Comment: So, if you had in mind to simply implement a statically pinned key in your app, I think it's dangerous. Microsoft can change the public key when they want. For instance, is their private key is stolen, they will generate a new certificate with a new public key (and they will revoke the previous certificate). In such a case, you application will see a new key, but should not stop the request.

Comment: I've updated my answer to take into account the disccusion in comments.